# How to get the list of EC2 instances created by Member users in OU in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-organizations

I have my AWS account. I have created multiple **member users** instead of IAM Users. 
Memebers usera has created multiple EC2 instances & other resources.
Can we get a list of running instances created by memeber users, through CLI ?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Could you please Edit your question and add more details? For example, what do you mean by "Member users in OU"? What do you mean by "list of EC2 instances for the member users"? How are the EC2 instances associated with these "members"?

Comment: How can we get the list of running instances in AWS through AWS CLI

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you asked: "How can we get the list of running instances in AWS through AWS CLI"

This AWS CLI command will list instances filtered by State, returning the Instance ID:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId --output text
```

This will list all running Amazon EC2 instances in your account for the default region that you have defined in the AWS CLI configuration.

It is *not* possible to limit the listing to only instances launched by specific people. Once an instance is launched, it belongs to the AWS Account and is not associated with a specific IAM User. If you wish to track usage by specific users, either add a **Tag** to the resource or use **AWS CloudTrail** to identify who launched the instance.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. The above command shows the list of running instances created by IAM Users. But in our scenario i have an AWS account, in which i have created an OU (Organizational Unit) & we have created many users inside this OU. Now we would like to list the instances, created by these users.  If you could do a favor in this cause i shall be highly obliged to you.  Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not possible. Instances are associated with an AWS Account. They are _not_ associated with the IAM User that launched the instance. You would need to examine records in AWS CloudTrail to discover who launched the instances. Alternatively, you could require that people add a Tag when launching their instance, so you can identify who launched it.